# Is it possible to send custom exit codes with casperjs?

Tags: casperjs

Currently failed tests send and exit code of 1 and successful ones send an exit code of 0. Can I have casper send an exit code of 2 on certain cases ?

Update in question:

Is it possible for casper to set a status code of (say) 2 and keep continuing with the remaining tests ?

Answer (score 0):

In a non-test environment, you can use `casper.exit(2);` to exit with a specific code.

---

In a test environment this is a little harder, because the execution is done in `casper.test.begin` functions.
For example, you can use the last test case in a file to set the exit code:

```js
casper.test.begin("test desc 1", function(test){
    ...
});
...
casper.test.begin("test desc last", function(test){
    casper.exit(2);
});
```

It might be better to use the `exit` event handler, though.

```js
var code = 0;
casper.on("exit", function(code){
    if (code > 0) {
        phantom.exit(2); // immediately exits
    }
});
casper.test.begin("test desc 1", function(test){
    ...
    if (!this.visible("something")) {
        code = 3;
    }
    ...
});
...
```

Comment: Both suggestions are untested.

Comment: Those suggestions cannot be used to one specific test case, but only file wise. I will see if I can come up with something else. ... try-catch might work.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with that ? I am still stuck there